SwiftData - Fatal error: Unexpected type for CompositeAttribute
I'm facing an issue when working with SwiftData (I feel certain I'm not alone) in the pet project I'm working on moving to SwiftData.
I re-created the issue(s) with the SwiftData example project below
As you might think, I'm not super experienced with SwiftData but I couldn't really find any helpful documentation on this yet. As per official docs, anything conforming to Codable should be good for SwiftData.
FYI:
In my pet project, the example basically maps to me storing players (Item) & each player containing a GameStatistics class (MyDictionaryWrapper) that stores a dictionary of [Game: Statistic] (here I'm using String: String for simplicity).

v1 -> This causes SwiftData - Fatal error: Unexpected type for CompositeAttribute: MyDictionaryWrapper
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    
    var testProperty: MyDictionaryWrapper = MyDictionaryWrapper()
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}

class MyDictionaryWrapper: Codable {
    var stats: [String: String] = [:]
    
    init(stats: [String : String] = [:]) {
        self.stats = stats
    }
}

v2 -> This causes  Fatal error: failed to find a currently active container for MyDictionaryWrapper
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    
    var testProperty: MyDictionaryWrapper = MyDictionaryWrapper()
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }
}

@Model
class MyDictionaryWrapper {
    var stats: [String: String] = [:]
    
    init(stats: [String : String] = [:]) {
        self.stats = stats
    }
}

// ModelContainer setup (Xcode 15.3 SwiftData template)

import SwiftData

@main
struct SwiftDataTestApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Customer.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}


Which idea / direction is the right one?
And what approach should I follow to fix it?
Should I reconsider the way I'm modelling my data to begin with?

Welcome to SO. Can you show how you set up the container. I.e the list of types.

V1, try struct instead of class and see if that helps. V2, maybe you just need to clean and rebuild but I would also use the @Relationship property wrapper on testProperty

I updated the original post to include the container! Its the template from Xcode 15.3 for SwiftData.
As suggested by Joakim, moving to structs instead of classes actually worked. Not 100% sure why but that did the trick. Thank you!


V1, try struct instead of class and see if that helps

Thank you for the suggestion Joakim Danielson!
I can't explain why it worked but it did.
Will have to learn a bit more about SwiftData while proceeding.
Thanks to all who replied and had a look at my post :)

I am pretty sure it's mentioned somewhere in the documentation that you can use custom struct's and enum's as attribute types
